# Close firebase connection after loading items

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My aim is to reduce simultaneous connection to firebase.
So, I have an idea of closing the connection after loading data from firebase.
So, how can I listen the end of loading data.

Comment: you can remove listener using `databaseReference.removeEventListener(this);`

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase Database client will automatically close the connection if there are no active listeners, and have been no writes for a few minutes.

If you want to more actively control the connection status, you can call [`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#goOffline()) and [`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#goOnline()) explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply